# Bad access exception on attempt to strlen a C string in Objective C on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Second line throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. I'm not too familiar with Objective C or C, but an SDK I'm using takes C parameters. What am I doing wrong here?

```
unsigned char *header = (unsigned char*)[
    [ticket_design objectForKey:@"header"]
    cStringUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
];
int header_length = strlen((const char*)header);
```

Comment: This does not look like C to me. What is it?

Comment: Did you check that header isn't NULL? BTW, the casts are unnecessary. `header` here should just be a `const char *`

Comment: @wildplasser it's objective-c

Comment: FYI, `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` is not an encoding. The method is almost certainly just interpreting this as `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, without necessarily allowing lossy encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I would just go the standard route by making `header` an `NSString` and then:

```
int len = [myString length];
```

I think this would prevent the ugly crash... but it seems like `header`is empty *or not null terminated.*